# How to solve $\min_{\mathbf{x}\in \{\pm 1\}^N} \lVert \operatorname{sign}(\mathbf{Wx}) - \mathbf{y} \rVert_2^2$ where $\mathbf{y}\in \{\pm 1\}^N$?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, combinatorial-optimization

Given the matrix $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ and the vector $\mathbf{y} \in \{\pm 1\}^N$, how to solve

$$\min_{\mathbf{x}\in \{\pm 1\}^N} \left\| \operatorname{sign}(\mathbf{Wx}) - \mathbf{y} \right\|_2^2$$

where $\operatorname{sign}(\cdot)$ is applied elementwise to a vector?

I have tried $\mathbf{x} = \operatorname{sign}\left(\mathbf{W}^{-1}\mathbf{y}\right)$ and $\mathbf{x} = \operatorname{sign}\left(\mathbf{W}^{T}\mathbf{y}\right)$ but found they don't work well.

This optimization problem was formulated while reading literature on neural networks, namely, [Hopfield networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_network).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/444875/2), note that bare `\|` doesn't indicate whether it is opening or closing, and so spaces poorly with `\operatorname`d operators. Consider, for example, $\|\operatorname{sign}(\cdot)\|$ `\|\operatorname{sign}(\cdot)\|` vs. $\lVert\operatorname{sign}(\cdot)\rVert$ `\lVert\operatorname{sign}(\cdot)\rVert`. I edited accordingly. This effect can also be accomplished with `\left\|` and `\right\|`, as you did in the body, but that can have a jarring effect: e.g., $\displaystyle\left\|a_{\frac1 2}\right\|$ is too big for many people.

Comment: Denoting the rows of $\mathbf{W}$ by $\mathbf{w}_1,\dots,\mathbf{w}_n$ and setting $\mathbf{v}_i:=y_i\mathbf{w}_i$, the problem turns into finding the largest $k$ with the property that the region of $\Bbb{R}^n$ described by $\langle v_{i_j},\mathbf{x}\rangle< 0$ ($i_1<\dots<i_k$) contains a point from $\{-1,1\}^n$.